# Compare only part of two of three items in triple

Tags: python, list, duplicates, append

I have a list that goes something like this, and new content is added in a loop.

```
list = [("banana", "a", 0), ("banana", "b", 1), ("coconut", "a", 2)]
```

In the loop I want to add items like so:

```
list.append(("strawberry", "b", 4))
```

however, this cannot occur if the first and second item in that sequence is already in the list together. For instance, the following list cannot be added to `list` because the first item already contains "banana" together with "a".

```
("banana", "a", 5) # Should NOT be appended
("banana", "c", 6) # SHOULD be appended
("strawberry", "a", 7) # SHOULD be appended
```

In a regular list we'd do something like the following to avoid duplicates:

```
if not item in list:
  list.append(item)
```

but note that my case does only involve partial duplicate, i.e. the first two items cannot be identical between sublists.

I am looking for a very efficient solution because the list can contain thousands of items.

Comment: I think you actually want to `list.append(("strawberry", "b", 4))` (better) or `list.extend([("strawberry", "b", 4)])` instead of `list.extend(("strawberry", "b", 4))`

Comment: @janbrohl You are right! Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend using a *dictionary* for this type of data coupling structure, along with **O(1)** look-up times, you'll also be implementing better design. However, you could do this with your current data structure using the following:

**Sample output:**

*With current structure*:

```
l = [ ("banana", "a", 0), ("banana", "b", 1), ("coconut", "a", 2) ]
items_to_add = [("banana", "a", 5), ("banana", "c", 6), ("strawberry", "a", 7)]

for item_to_add in items_to_add:
    if not item_to_add[:2] in [i[:2] for i in l]:
        l.append(item_to_add)
print l
>>> [('banana', 'a', 0), ('banana', 'b', 1), ('coconut', 'a', 2), 
('banana', 'c', 6), ('strawberry', 'a', 7)]
```

Other wise, you can use a dictionary (*factor out your two first elements to be your key*):

*With dictionary*:

```
d = { ("banana", "a") : 0, ("banana", "b") : 1, ("coconut", "a") : 2 }
items_to_add = [("banana", "a", 5), ("banana", "c", 6), ("strawberry", "a", 7)]

for item_to_add in items_to_add:
    key = item_to_add[:2]
    value = item_to_add[-1]
    if not key in d:
        d[key] = value 
print d
>>> {('coconut', 'a'): 2, ('strawberry', 'a'): 7, ('banana', 'c'): 6, 
('banana', 'a'): 0, ('banana', 'b'): 1}
```

A dictionary works very well in this scenario as you're trying to leverage properties of **key/value** data structure. Unique keys are ensured, and this will be the most efficient route as well.

Answer (score 1):

you may check the presence of an new item with

```
#check for every item if newItem matches an Item in the list
if not any( True for item in list if newItem[:2]==item[:2] ): 
    # add your newItem
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use tuples as keys in a dictionary:

```
fruits = {
    ('banana', 'a'): 0,
    ('banana', 'b'): 1,
    ('coconut', 'a'): 2,
}
```

Then, you can just check if `(item[0], item[1])` is already in the dictionary:

```
item = ('strawberry', 'b', 4)
if (item[0], item[1]) not in fruits:
    fruits[item[0], item[1]] = item[2]
```

If you want to preserve order, you can use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of the built-in dictionary.

This avoids using more memory to store a set of keys and is also efficient regarding lookup.

Comment: And how could I efficiently compare the keys from a new item with all the keys from the list? (I am not proficient in Python...)

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [("banana", "a", 0), ("banana", "b", 1), ("coconut", "a", 2)]
items = [("banana", "a", 5), ("banana", "c", 6), ("strawberry", "a", 7)]

for item in items:
    if item[:2] not in map(lambda x: x[:2], data):
        data.append(item)
```

Output:

```
    [('banana', 'a', 0),
     ('banana', 'b', 1),
     ('coconut', 'a', 2),
     ('banana', 'c', 6),
     ('strawberry', 'a', 7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A time-efficient solution would be to keep a `set` with added items

```
li = [("banana", "a", 0), ("banana", "b", 1), ("coconut", "a", 2)]
se= set(t[:2] for t in li)

add=[
("banana", "a", 5), # Should NOT be appended
("banana", "c", 6), # SHOULD be appended
("strawberry", "a", 7) # SHOULD be appended
]

for t in add:
     ct=t[:2]
     if ct not in se:
        li.append(t)
        se.add(ct)
```

after that, `li` is `[('banana', 'a', 0), ('banana', 'b', 1), ('coconut', 'a', 2), ('banana', 'c', 6), ('strawberry', 'a', 7)]`